# Command as Argument for Custom command does not work

Tags: macros, glossaries

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\newacronym{a}{A}{The one and only A}

\newcommand{\myCmd}[3][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
        {}%
        {\texthl{#2}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
        Test #3 %
    }{%
        Other Test #1 #3%
    }%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item works: \gls{a}
  \item works: \myCmd{1}{2}
  \item works: \myCmd[3]{1}{2}
  \item does not work: \myCmd[3]{\gls{a}}{2}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I know that `myCmd` looks weird, but that's only because I simplified a lot of it for the MWE.

Anyways, the MWE results in this error:

```
! Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `{a}' has not been defined.
```

The only thing I figured already is, that the `gls` command does not find the parameter, because it looks for `{a}` instead of `a` - but why?

Comment: `\gls` is not expandable, most likely this is the reason why the test fails!

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but what can I do beside "not using `\gls` as (part) of an argument"? Or is there nothing I can do about it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a work-around, with the expandable commands `\glsentryname` and `\glsentrydesc` (for more of them see section 9 of `glossaries-user.pdf` documentation).

In order to calm `soul` and 'expand' the argument, an `\mbox{}` is appropiate. Long descriptions won't break however over lines.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nomain]{glossaries}

\newcommand{\glsinfo}[1]{%
  \glsentryname{#1} -- \glsentrydesc{#1}%
}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{a}{A}{The one and only A}

\newcommand{\myCmd}[3][]{%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{\texthl{\mbox{#2}}}%
  \ifblank{#1}{Test #3}{Other Test #1 #3}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item works: \gls{a}
  \item works: \myCmd{1}{2}
  \item works: \myCmd[3]{1}{2}
  \item works: \myCmd[3]{\glsinfo{a}}{2}
  \item works: \myCmd[3]{\glsentrydesc{a}}{2}
  \item works: \myCmd[3]{}{2}
\end{itemize}

%\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A better solution requires more information on the intentions what the code should do actually.